# How to create this "image-overlap-div" layout while keeping it responsive with CSS and/or JS? (See Image example)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How would you position the image (dark rectangle) to overlap the background solid-color-full-width div exactly as pictured (at a point of about 60% height), while keeping in the same across different screen sizes (responsive)?
[image: desktop and mobile layout with image]

I've tried placing the background color div as first HTML element and applying this CSS:

```
.full-width-hero-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
```

While the rest of the content is in normal flow in a flex container. This worked for my screen, but resizing the window makes the background resize too. So in large screens the background is larger in height than the top image, making the image appear inside of it.

I guess I could use CSS media queries and adjust the background size manually, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: Why would you absolutely position that one? The lines on this in your images suggest this is not a simple background, but contains text itself ...? If anything, I would absolutely position the dark rectangle here.

Comment: @CBroe It's a simple solid color background. The text and image content is in normal flow in another container. If I absolutely positioned the dark rectangle (image) than I'll have to use a whole lot of media queries to adjust it's position as content height changes across screen sizes...

Comment: _"The text and image content is in normal flow in another container."_ - then what should the _"at a point of about 60% height"_ be based on? Questions like this should really come with a proper [mre], rather than just a vague & ambiguous verbal description of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this can help, using "margin-top" I set content on image.

```css
    body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main-hero {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.main-hero .image-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 800px;
}

.main-hero .content {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: -150px auto 0 auto;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px #0000008a;
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.main-hero .content p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*//for tablet*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .main-hero .content {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
}

/*//for mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .main-hero .content {
       max-width: 210px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: -80px auto 0 auto;
    }
    .main-hero .content p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-hero">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643303808869-ecfbf62fe81e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Main Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```